# Blazor Wasm Hosted Client Side (console) Exception After Release

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm app that Hosted in Asp .Net Core 5 web API. All Generated with vs 2019 template with auth.
In debug or Release build everything works Perfectly. But after I Publish this app in Folder Profile, then run, I have these Exceptions in browser console:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Arg_NullReferenceException
System.NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException
   at Chatory.Client.Components.Contacts.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<BuildRenderTree>b__1(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

and another :

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Arg_NullReferenceException
System.NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException
   at Chatory.Client.Components.Contacts.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<BuildRenderTree>b__1(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

because i don't have those exceptions in build (debug/release) time, i cant debug it!!! those exceptions just appear after publish!!!

any idea to solve this problem???

-------------........................---------------------

I Did Clean and Rebuild Solution... do not help...